# Run JSOM with Site Collection Admin permission

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, permissions, jsom, runwithelevatedprivileges

Is it possible to run JSOM with Site Collection Admin permission anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only by having a Site Collection Admin login and run the code (Access a page with it)